# value.length < 10 return false not working

Tags: javascript, forms

I was using a condition onsubmit to return false if the text field didn't have more than 10 characters however it stopped submitting at all just now, I don't think I changed anything less the condition but obviously I must have done something.

```
<form class="form-new" action="insert/insert.php" method="post" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('post-input').value.length < 10) return false;">
    <textarea class="form-new" id="post-input" name="text"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ciudad" value="<?=$city;?>">
    <input type="text" name="colegio" value="<?=$group;?>">
    <input class="form-new" type="submit" value="Publicar"/>
</form>
```

Is there a way round? Or am I just doing it wrong? Thanks

Comment: "Works" here: http://jsfiddle.net/MBawQ/

Comment: It works for me as well, did you check if some other JS is breaking it? What does firebug says?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Why doesn't it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/YNcU4/ ?

Comment: @Naor: Your `submit` handler does not return the value from `checkLength()`. Should be `onsubmit="return checkLength()"`.

Comment: @Naor - because you need `onsubmit="return checkLength()"` - you forgot the all important `return`.

Comment: @Jamiec,@Felix Kling: You right.. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/YNcU4/).

But have a look, if you return false in onsubmit the form will be sent anyway. In order to perform alert or something like that, you should do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkLength() {
        var textarea=document.getElementById('post-input');
    alert(textarea.value.length >= 10);
        if (textarea.value.length >= 10) {
            document.getElementById('myform').submit();
        }
    }
</script>

<form class="form-new" action="insert/insert.php" id="myform" method="post">
    <textarea class="form-new" id="post-input" name="text"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ciudad" value="<?=$city;?>">
    <input type="text" name="colegio" value="<?=$group;?>">
    <input class="form-new" type="button" value="Publicar" onclick="checkLength()"/>
</form>
```

and this is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/YNcU4/1/.

**UPDATE:** Please read comments. The original code should work.

Comment: No, if you return false from `onsubmit`, the form shouldnt post.

Comment: Binding the validation to the `submit` event is better than binding it to the `click` event of the submit button. A form can be submitted without clicking the button. `return false` also works for the `submit` event. And besides that, it JS is disabled, your form will become useless.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Agree with you - my mistake.